# Create a shared folder for KVM Windows guest on Ubuntu server 20.04 or properly set up NAT connection

Tags: networking, server, virtualization, kvm-virtualization

Hi I am posting this because all of the guides I can find involve a GUI. I am using Ubuntu server and controlling it with cockpit. I installed the following packages to get virtual machines working: qemu qemu-kvm libvirt-daemon libvirt-clients bridge-utils virt-manager. I can use my Windows 10 Pro guest from the web interface, but I need it to save my DVR recordings to /Data/Tank/Plex/Playon. If I go set up NAT, the virtual machine says the cable is unplugged... so I can't get it to show up on my network, I was hoping to use samba. I then tried an alternative, mounting a shared folder to the virtual machine. I can't find a guide that works only through command line interface. Can anyone help me get either of these solutions to work? I have been at this for three days and followed many guides one of which told me to install gdm which gave me a very broken GUI, that took a long time to fix because I didn't have terminal or SSH. The IP addresses that are generated don't match my network. My Gateway is 192.168.50.1, Thanks for your help!
[image: This is the VM page for Cockpit]

Comment: NAT communication won't work well once you want to gave the guest to be discoverable. You can consider either creating a real bridge and use that network which will make the VM appear on the network as any other of your computers (see https://netplan.io/examples/#configuring-network-bridges). Or (without network setup) you can use either the older 9pfs or virtio-fs (depends on the versions you are using) to share host/guest folder (see "Sharing files between Host<->Guest" at https://ubuntu.com/server/docs/virtualization-libvirt)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I will have that a try. I only need this VM to save DVR recordings to the server and for our tv to see it and request for movies to be recorded.

Answer (score 0):

I found that the easiest way in NAT is connect to the guest via Remmina and make the configuration for a shared folder. Also the real bridge, but that has been mentioned and that solution works better.

Comment: Thanks. I'll give it a try. I don't have a working solution yet. My current goal is to increase my network and server security.